# Android Dialog, Black text on black background?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to set the Background of a ListView in a Dialog to be white and the text black. The following code produces a dialog with black words on a black background. My contextmenu looks correct with black words on white background.

```
        dialog1 = new Dialog(this);         
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);            
        builder.setTitle("Select Color Mode");

        ListView modeList = new ListView(this);         
        String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
        modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
```

Am I missing something?

Just to add, I set the theme to Light.

Comment: hmm .. I guess we can customize the view for list rows by extending through base adapter. there you can decide what should be the background and foreground colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom adapter :

In `getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)`

You can then call `setBackgroundColor() / setBackgroundDrawable() / setBackgroundResource()` for each list item

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to change the background color of the listview:

```
dialog1.getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```